# How do you calculate the break even price point for a crypto trade with fees?

Tags: trading, cryptocurrency

Consider the following problem:

**LIMIT BUY**

```
Total: €1,000 (starting balance)
BTC Price #1: €50,000
Fee: 1,000 * 0.5% = €5
Amount: 1,000 - 5 = €995
Purchase BTC: 995 / 50,000 = ₿0.0199
```

**LIMIT SELL**

```
Amount: ₿0.0199
BTC Price #2: €50,503.77516 (brute forced)
Sell BTC: 0.0199 * 50,503.77516 = €1,005.025126
Fee: 1,005.025126 * 0.5% = €5.025125628
Total: 1,005.025126 - 5.025125628 ≈ €1,000 (break even)
```

**Question:** How do you find the break even sales price without brute-forcing? (And is there something else I've missed?)

Note: On Coinbase Pro both maker and taker fees for volumes of less than $10k per month is 0.5%, so we can assume that it's the same no matter which deal you get. However it would still be useful to see an answer that uses different fee structures for maker and taker trades.

Comment: Well, 'a' = 1000 * 0.005 while 'b' = (1000 + 'a') * 0.005 . Then 1000 - 'a' relates to 50000 as 1000 + 'b' relates to 'x'. Finally, 'x' = 1005.025 * 50000 / 995 .

Comment: that solves my problem pretty neatly! Thank you! If you write it as an answer, you can score more points.

Comment: I suppose that the question lacks broad appeal but it's not being closed. The problem is interesting in that a small amount of algebra and logic is required before setting up a proportion of equivalent fractions.

Comment: Someone seems to have censored my legitimate complaint that an equally legitimate question is being downvoted, presumably because it's "too stupid". Look, if you want more contributors on this site, you can't very well treat people who are humbly asking for help like that. I think such behaviour reflects very badly on the Stack Exchange, and it's the number one reason people are hesitant about using it at all, especially when you're in effect being punished simply for asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> Amount: ₿0.0199
> BTC Price #2: €50,503.77516 (brute forced)
> Sell BTC: 0.0199 * 50,503.77516 = €1,005.025126
> Fee: 1,005.025126 * 0.5% = €5.025125628
> Total: 1,005.025126 - 5.025125628 ≈ €1,000 (break even)
> ```

If you take this the other way round, you are at the result:

```
Sell amount = 1000 + Fee = 1000 / .995 = 1005.0251256281407
```

so your price is

```
1005.0251256281407 / .0199 = 50503.775157193
```

Why `/ .995`? Well, in this step you have to do the opposite of what you do in your part.

And as `a - a * .005 = a * .995 =: b`, `a = b / .995` (where a = 1005.02512562814, b = 1000)